# Composer: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: composer-php

I am trying to install a composer package and I continuously get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
    - The requested package rondobley/extended-respect-validation could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

Here is the composer.json

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "rondobley/extended-respect-validation": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

And the output from composer install -vvv:

```
vagrant@wheezy:/code/test$ composer install -vvv
Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: valid
Executing command (/code/test): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/code/test): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (/code/test): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /home/vagrant/.composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Running 1.2.0 (2016-07-19 01:28:52) with PHP 5.5.38-1~dotdeb+7.1 on Linux / 3.2.0-4-amd64
Loading composer repositories with package information
Downloading https://packagist.org/packages.json
Writing /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/packages.json into cache
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2013.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2014.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2015-10.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2016-01.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2016-04.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-2016-07.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-archived.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/p-provider-latest.json from cache
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Dependency resolution completed in 0.001 seconds
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package rondobley/extended-respect-validation could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

The package seems to be fine to me:

https://packagist.org/packages/rondobley/extended-respect-validation

It is a new package, just published today, but it has been several hours. I have also tried `composer clearcache` and that does not help. I have read many of the other similar issues here with no luck. I am new to publishing composer packages, so maybe I an missing a simple step?

Ideally I would like to install version ^1.0.